# Kotlin type inference failed

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

Let's say we have a 3rd-party Java library with such class:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package foo;

public final class Functions {
  public interface VoidFunc0 {
    void call();
  }

  public interface VoidFunc1<T> {
    void call(T t);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> NoOpFunc<T> noOp() {
    return new NoOpFunc();
  }

  /*public*/ static final class NoOpFunc<T> implements VoidFunc0, VoidFunc1<T> {
    @Override public void call() { /* deliberately no op */}
    @Override public void call(T t) { /* deliberately no op */ }
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

We successfully used its `Functions.noOp()`  method in our Java application, but when we began to rewrite it in Kotlin, we faced the issue that the code below doesn't compile and gives us two errors:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package bar

import foo.Functions

object KotlinApp {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        /*
         * Error:(XX, XX) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information
         * to infer parameter T in fun <T : Any!> noOp(): Functions.NoOpFunc<T!>!
         * Please specify it explicitly.
         */
        callVoidFunc0(Functions.noOp()) // ERROR 1
        /*
         * Error:(XX, XX) Kotlin: Type Functions.NoOpFunc<Any!>! is inaccessible
         * in this context due to: Functions.NoOpFunc<Any!>!
         */
        callVoidFunc1(Functions.noOp()) // ERROR 2
    }

    fun callVoidFunc0(func0: Functions.VoidFunc0) {
        func0.call()
    }

    fun callVoidFunc1(func1: Functions.VoidFunc1<Any>) {
        func1.call("A")
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but the same code previously written in Java compiles and works well:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package bar;

import foo.Functions;

public class JavaApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    callVoidFunc0(Functions.noOp()); // OK
    callVoidFunc1(Functions.noOp()); // OK
  }

  public static void callVoidFunc0(Functions.VoidFunc0 func0) {
    func0.call();
  }

  public static void callVoidFunc1(Functions.VoidFunc1<Object> func1) {
    func1.call("A");
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Type inference fails even if we specify `T`  explicitly. Error 2 goes away when `NoOpFunc` declared as `public`, but Error 1 still remains.

Comment: `It cannot infer the type of T0 which is actually Action0` - `Action0` is not generic, so `T0` is used for `Action1`, `Action2`, etc. Not that it answers your question though.

Comment: You need to make the sample small and self contained, not referencing an outside code link.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is a bug in Kotlin.
Here's the link to the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14499. Please vote.

**UPD**
To fix the issue there's a workaround:

```
@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    @Suppress("INACCESSIBLE_TYPE")
    callVoidFunc0(Functions.noOp())      // (1)

    @Suppress("INACCESSIBLE_TYPE")
    callVoidFunc1(Functions.noOp<Any>()) // (2)
}
```

To fix (1) one must suppress the compilation warning, to fix (2) - additionally specify the type explicitly.